Transparent textures cast opaque shadows, even when the shadow mode is set to alpha clip
Like the title says, the textures with alpha in my scene cast opaque shadows, even when the shadow mode is set to alpha clip. Most of the geometry in the offending areas are flat planes. Transparent shadows are enabled on all surfaces. What gives?

Bizarrely, some textures are working as intended, such as the shadows on the antlers, casting on the exact same surface no less!

Usually with Alpha Clip I would say there is a problem with either the Clip Threshold value being too high or too low (depending on what the issue in various cases might be) or with the Alpha channel itself. The default threshold of 0.5 seems okay to me if the alpha mask is correct - which I cannot see in the screenshot. So it would be interesting to know what the output there is.

@GordonBrinkmann What issue would happen with the alpha mask that would cause the geometry to clip properly but not its shadow?
I messed around with the threshold, but it didn't change anything.
Oh, and I'm using the alpha from a PNG image rather than a proper mask if that changes anything.

In your case nothing I guess, since Blend Mode and Shadow Mode both use Clip - but some people use different settings. It's hard to tell without seeing all the settings to remember all possible issues. In EEVEE there are also shadow settings in the render properties and the light source properties etc. Maybe we need your file or parts of it where we have at least the object, the light source, the image texture packed in the file and all scene settings like in the original project.
